# Embedded google map not appearring as I choose

Tags: google-maps

I am using the link iframe code, directly from the google maps site, but the map when rendered on the page is very different. It is too close and it lacks the custom objects I have placed on the map.

[The map is saved and public.](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&ll=51.445288,-2.076073&spn=0.034879,0.090895&z=14&msid=105969386264938156859.0004933a7b5534e8bb519)

```
    <iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
 marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&
amp;msid=105969386264938156859.0004933a7b5534e8bb519&amp;ll=51.442667,-2.076416&
amp;spn=0.032099,0.051327&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>View
 <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&
amp;msid=105969386264938156859.0004933a7b5534e8bb519&amp;ll=51.442667,-2.076416&
amp;spn=0.032099,0.051327&amp;z=13&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;
text-align:left">Fitzgraham Academy of Dance</a> in a larger map</small>
```

Answer (score 1):

The embedded maps are shaky at best, I recommend you look into Google Maps API and program a perfect map for yourself

I suggest you look at this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). It allows you to control the content a lot better. If you have any issues look at the source code on the [Samples.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html)